# Downloaded XML file losing all XML tags

Tags: c#

I am trying to download an xml file from a web page. Once it saves, it loses all of the XML formatting making passing fail (however, right clicking and Save As. on the webpage saves it correctly). Is there something I am doing wrong, or another option?

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
                client.DownloadFile(url, "my.xml");
                
            }
```

Picture on the left is from right clicking and Save As. on the site. Picture on the right is the output from the above code.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to download and what are you getting? The question needs to be improved.

Comment: Downloading an API page, thats in .xml format. And I am getting, a .xml document missing all the xml tags (ie <Tag1>test</Tag1> gets converted to "Tag1":test). It almost looks like a .csv file

Comment: @dwb Could you show us what XML will look like?

Comment: @D-Shih added a screenshot

Comment: @dwb Could you provide **text** format data instead of Images thanks? BTW you are looking for xml to Json

Comment: @D-Shih I would prefer to not post the entire documents, I could provide offline however.

Comment: @dwb I know just mock as a sample data instead of real data, we need to know schema from your data structure